# Loading Log4j.properties from outside of the war without spring framework

Tags: java, jboss, log4j

I'm going to load log4j.properties outside of war file. I have done some research on the net but all solutions I have found is spring enabled projects which I don't use. I'm using WildFly(Jboss) as my Application server. any idea?